# Examples of smooth varieties with nonvanishing cohomologies of tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a reasonably simple example of a smooth variety $X$ (over complex numbers) with the properties that $H^0(T_X)\neq 0$ and $H^1(T_X)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 5):

In dimension $1$, elliptic curves are examples.  In dimension 2, every Hirzebruch surface except $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\text{Bl}_{p}(\mathbb{P}^2)$ are examples.

Comment: In any dimension, abelian varieties